# How to update your database from a tabulator action link

Tags: javascript, express, tabulator

I am trying to send my tabulator row data to my server because i want to delete it from my database `onClick` of the distribute button but i cannot seem to figure that out. I have added a fetch function that should post to the specified express route which is not receiving that request. Someone kindly let me know how to solve this

Here is my script tag:

```js
function btnFormatter( cell, params, onRendered ) {
    var element = document.createElement('button');
    var link = document.createElement('a')
    link.textContent = 'Distribute'
    link.className = "button-link"
    element.appendChild(link)
    
  
    onRendered( function() {
        element.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        var id = cell.getData().id
        const data = cell.getRow().getData()

        fetch('http://localhost:3000/delete/marketing', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
    })

    return element;
}

var table = new Tabulator(".table", {
    height:'auto', // set height of table (in CSS or here), this enables the Virtual DOM and improves render speed dramatically (can be any valid css height value)
    ajaxURL:'/marketing.json', //load data
    layout:"fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
    columns:[ //Define Table Columns
        {title:"Customer Name", field:"name"},
        {title:"Commodity", field:"commodity",headerFilter:'input'},
        {title:"Quality", field:"quality",headerFilter:'input'},
        {title:"Quantity", field:"quantity"},
        {title:'Action',formatter:btnFormatter}
    ],
    // rowClick:function(e, row){ //trigger an alert message when the row is clicked
    //     alert("Row " + row.getData().id + " Clicked!!!!");
    // },
});
```

And my express route:

```js
router.post('/delete/marketing',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body)
    // connection.query('DELETE FROM order_table WHERE id = ?', req.body.id,(error,results)=>{
    //     if(error){
    //         console.log('error')
    //     } else {
    //         console.log('item deleted')
    //     }
    // })
})
```

Comment: Dont put it in your onRendered() handler. Move it up to where you are defining the the element. TBH, I'm not even sure when onRendered handlers get called, I've never had to use them.

Comment: This still does not work

Comment: Works fine (https://jsfiddle.net/okemyLfv/)
PS: You'll need the Debugger to see it sent google.com the body, coz google didnt actually process the request. But the button clicks and sends...